# Get all users invited by someone discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I wanted to know if you guys know how to a invite count of all users that have been invited by someone, I use discord.js. Thanks You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No really a direct way to do it but one method is to fetch the invites and then filter by the member and then count all the usages up:

```js
// guild = <Guild>
// member = <Member>
//needs to be in an async function
const invites = await guild.fetchInvites();
let amount = 0;

invites.forEach(invite => {
   if(!invite.inviter || invite.inviter.id !== member.id) return;
   amount += invite.uses;
});

console.log(uses);
```